# change the value of the 'return' ("wait ...") by an image

Tags: javascript

Well, I understand very little of JavaScript and tou with a little problem ... I'll try to explain:
I put a player (ready code) of music on my site and it happens that has a function that before loading the audio time (mm: ss) shows "wait ..." and I wanted to replace this text with an image gif loading but do not know how ... is this possible?

```
// Convert seconds to mm:ss format
  function toTimeString(seconds) {
    if (isNaN(seconds)) {
      return "wiat...";
    }
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds = seconds - minutes * 60;
    return zeroPad(minutes, 2) + ":" + zeroPad(seconds, 2);
  }
```

Please answer me if only to say that this is no way for me to not spend the rest of my life behind it hahahah. Good evening!
[image exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvFOj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Odds are, you can just return HTML for the image instead of the "wait..." text.

Something like:

```
return '<img src="path/to/your/image.png"/>';
```

This isn't guaranteed to work, it depends on how `toTimeString` is being used. So beyond that I would need more context.